# How to add project key value to sonarqube dashboard?

Tags: sonarqube

I am using SonarQube 6.4

Does anyone how I can include the project key value to the sonarqube dashboard?

Answer (score 2):

Configurable dashboards were dropped in SonarQube 6.2. The Project Homepage which replaces project dashboards, is not configurable.

Fortunately, project key is displayed automatically at the bottom-right of the project homepage.